# Sending an email to from VM with exim4 to VM with posfix

Tags: linux, networking, email, exim

I have two virtual machines and both running Ubuntu server. I should be able to send emails from lab2 to lab1 using `mail`. lab2 is running `exim4`and lab1 has `postfix` listening on port 25. I should configure exim on lab2, so that it delivers the emails that are for lab1 to lab1, and for lab2 to lab2. It works fine when I send emails with `mail` from lab2 to lab2, but I get an error when sending from lab2 to lab1. As I understand `exim` should work as a relay for lab1? The error I get is `R=dnslookup_relay_to_domains defer (-1): host lookup did not complete`, below more details.

From lab2 I can `ping` and `ssh` to lab1. Can anybody help me understanding what I am doing wrong? I have tried changing the configuration of exim but I am sure there is something I am not understanding here...

**On lab1**

The ip address of lab1:

```
user@lab1:~$ ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d5:ec:9a  
          inet addr:10.0.2.5  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Postfix is listening on port 25:

```
user@lab1:~$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

**On lab2**

The content of `/etc/hosts`:

```
user@lab2:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   lab2
10.0.2.5    lab1
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Part of the content of `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated`:

```
# the following macro definitions were created
# dynamically by /usr/sbin/update-exim4.conf
.ifndef MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES
MAIN_LOCAL_INTERFACES=<; 127.0.0.1; 10.0.2.6
.endif
.ifndef MAIN_PACKAGE_VERSION
MAIN_PACKAGE_VERSION=4.86.2-2ubuntu2.3
.endif
.ifndef MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS
MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS=@:localhost:lab2: localhost
.endif
.ifndef MAIN_RELAY_TO_DOMAINS
MAIN_RELAY_TO_DOMAINS=lab1
.endif
.ifndef ETC_MAILNAME
ETC_MAILNAME=lab2
.endif
.ifndef LOCAL_DELIVERY
LOCAL_DELIVERY=maildir_home
.endif
.ifndef MAIN_RELAY_NETS
MAIN_RELAY_NETS=10.0.2.0/8 : 127.0.0.1 : ::::1
.endif
.ifndef DCreadhost
DCreadhost=empty
.endif
.ifndef DCsmarthost
DCsmarthost=mail.lab2
.endif
.ifndef DC_eximconfig_configtype
DC_eximconfig_configtype=internet
.endif
.ifndef DCconfig_internet
DCconfig_internet=1
.endif
```

Sending the email from lab2 to user on lab1:

`user@lab2:~$ echo "test" | mail -s test user@lab1`

Output of `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`:

```
2019-01-26 01:31:24 1gnBsa-0000PD-2b <= user@lab2 U=user P=local S=310
2019-01-26 01:31:24 1gnBsa-0000PD-2b == user@lab1 R=dnslookup_relay_to_domains defer (-1): host lookup did not complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been trying many things and got a bit messed up with the configuration. Finally sorted it out and here is the correct configuration from `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='lab2; localhost'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='lab1'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

Basically using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` I had to choose the `mail sent by smarthost` option and then set `lab1` as smarthost.